# How can I assign a delegated jQuery event listener based on values in jQuery's data API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-data

jQuery treats data-attributes in an [interesting way](http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/09/using-jquerys-data-apis), wherein it retrieves values *once* and does not observe changes or removals after that point. Modification of the data is achieved by using jQuery's various functions – `$element.data('key', 'val')` etc. As such, it muddies the code to do things like `$element.prop('data-key', 'val')` and `$element.removeProp('data-key', 'val')` because this *does not touch* the jQuery Data API, even though it would reasonably appear that these calls are intended to do that.

However, that means of altering the DOM seems to be the only way to successfully use data-attributes for delegated event listeners "the jQuery way:"

```
$element.on('click', '[data-key=val]', function(e) {
  // only triggers on children of $element that have the DOM attribute
  // data-attribute data-key, with a value of val
});
```

Data-attributes don't clog up classnames etc and seem like a reasonable place to put certain element attributes for JavaScript usage. But now if I write `$element.find('div').data('key', 'val')`, these elements will not meet the criteria when clicked. The only way to accomplish that is by saying `$element.find('div').prop('data-key', 'val')`, which is not a best practice as I understand it.

The other option is this:

```
$element.on('click', 'div', function(e) {
  if ($(this).data('key') != 'val') return;
  // handle
});
```

This seems clunky, and will trigger more frequently than the above. It's also a little less clear what we're actually targeting.

Were it not delegated, I could write:

```
$element.find('div')
  .filter(function() { return $(this).data('key') == 'val'; })
  .on('click', function(e) {
    // handle
  });
```

But `.filter()` won't work for delegated listeners, which only accept a string selector.

So the problem is this: I have multiple solutions already, but none are ideal, and none really follow jQuery's idiom. How can I assign delegated listeners based on the jQuery Data API?

Comment: What is application , expected result ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to more clearly explain it? I'd like to apply a delegated event listener based on jQuery Data that may change. Eg, I add a div, I don't want it clickable; something else happens, I apply `$div.data('clickable', true)`. Now I want it clickable based on the original event listener.

Comment: Try utilizing `Element.dataset` ; see post.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
$(document).on("click", "[data-clickable=true]", function(e) {
  alert(this.dataset.clickable)
});
// set `div` `dataset.clickable` to `true`
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("div")[0].dataset.clickable = true;
  $("[data-clickable=true]").html("clickable: true")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button>make `div` "clickable"</button>
<div data-clickable="false">clickable: false</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a7qcafwf/1/

Comment: This is interesting. Does `dataset` have any effect on the jQuery Data API, though? It doesn't seem to. So it seems like this is another (more modern) way of saying `$('div').prop('data-clickable', true)`

Comment: See linked article at _"Enter HTML5
A few years later, HTML5 became popular and associated another concept with the word "data" through its data-* attributes and the associated DOM .dataset property. This isn't quite the same as jQuery's original idea of data: It involves values being associated with HTML elements in markup and not DOM elements in memory. But they are logically close enough that we added the ability to read HTML5 data-* attributes into jQuery's data object starting with version 1.4."_ `jQuery.data()` or `.data()` _should_ read updated `html` `data-*` attributes

Comment: Would view source of current `jQuery.data` , `.data()` to be certain about how native `HTMLElement.dataset` parsed, related to jQuery implementation ; though use `HTMLElement.dataset` for type of application described at original post.

Comment: Yeah… I think maybe long-term, `.dataset` could _replace_ `$.data()`, but in the short term they don't update each other (as noted, jQuery only reads data from the HTML once, and that's where the dataset info gets stored). `.dataset` is IE11+ and that's probably the biggest stumbling block. Need to rely on `$.data()` for now.

Comment: Yes. Save for ie<11 native `HTMLElement.dataset` appear useful for such implementations. see source https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js . Did not attempt above with `.data()` or `jQuery.data()` , yet

Comment: Another possible approach is to utilize `MutationObserver` , or to modify `Jquery.data` at source to sync with `HTMLElement.dataset` modifications , and vise-versa - for ie applications.

Comment: MutationObserver is also IE11+ and is a really cool thing to look forward to but is separate from the jQuery Data API.

Comment: @BenSaufley `.attr()` appear compatible with `.data()` http://jsfiddle.net/a7qcafwf/2/ . `.on()` expecting selector string at that parameter. Appear would have to adjust or extend `.data()` to add attribute similar to `.attr()` , `.prop()` ; or, use `data` parameter of `.on()` to pass `.data()` - or create a custom event attach, dispatch handler ?